# Like sql statement not working

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
select sec_sec_nm,count(1)OVER() from nms_num_scheme 
where nms_sec_nm like 'CMIG4%';
```

This query runs in one Oracle DB.
But the same query does not return any data in other DB though data are available.

Comment: Do you get any result when you supply full value for the field in a = query.

Comment: @Taranath, please run `select sec_sec_nm, nms_sec_nm from nms_num_scheme` in both environments and examine the results. Either the data in the two databases is different, or something more complicated is happening (e.g. Row Level Security).

Comment: @Ertunç Yes 'CMIG4' is full name for an attribute. Is this quirey should not run for full value....????

Comment: @TaranathDatta there is no apparent reason for your query not to work. It should even work for full attribute value in Oracle. What is the other DB environment? Any error code or just empty result set?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT sec_sec_nm from nms_num_scheme where nms_sec_nm like 'CMIG4%';
```

I really don't know what you're trying to do with:

```
select sec_sec_nm,count(1)OVER()
```

But I don't think that will work at all.

Comment: SELECT sec_sec_nm from nms_num_scheme where nms_sec_nm like 'CMIG4%';  also not working. I dont know some change require or not.

Comment: @Ignacio, the `count(1)OVER()` is tangential to this question, but it is valid sql - it returns the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes, I know what the count(1) does (just never heard of over() in sql), which is returning the number of rows, just thought that it wasn't going to work like that so I wrote the query that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sec_sec_nm,count(1) cnt from nms_num_scheme 
where nms_sec_nm like 'CMIG4%'
group by sec_sec_nm
```